# jQuery DataTables and MVC Web API 2

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, datatable, asp.net-web-api2

I'm having a problem with `JSON` that is returned from my `API` `class` to my `JavaScript` and having it accepted by the `jQuery` `DataTable` I'm using. I keep getting an error saying invalid length or cannot find value c depending on the browser and I'm not sure what would fix it considering I do have it working in [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oheyb/2jgt3mn8/3/), just not in my code.

**Working Code**

```
$("#data-table").DataTable({
   serverSide: true,
   processing: true,
   columns : [
      { data : 'title' }
   ],    
   ajax: {
      url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/1z3k1",
      dataSrc : ''
   }
});
```

It's not pretty, but it takes the remote JSON location and puts it into the DataTable.

**Code I'm Working On:**

Now, this is what I have going into the API:

```
[Route("OMDB/GetMovie/{title}")]
public string GetMovie(string title)
{
   HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.myjson.com/bins/13zyh");
   HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
   StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
   String responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
   return responseString;
}
```

Now ideally this will eventually search by title, but for now I'm just trying to get it accept ANY json at all.

Here is also my JavaScript/HTML code:

```
<table id="data-table">
   <thead>
      <th>Title</th>
   </thead>
</table>

<script>
   var uri = '/OMDB/GetMovie/';
   var id = document.getElementById('MovieTitle').value;
   $("#data-table").DataTable({
      serverSide: true,
      processing: true,
      columns: [
         { data: 'title' }
      ],
      ajax: {
         url: uri + id
      }
    });
</script>
```

Nothing shows up in the tables, though it does pass back the same json as the `Jsfiddle` it seems.  I haven't been using the `DataTables` for a long time, so any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Seems that adding this has helped alleviate my issues with the DataTable

```
dataSrc: function (json) {
                        var obj = JSON.parse(json);
                        console.log(obj);
                        return obj;
                    }
```

Making the full script

```
$("#data-table").DataTable({
          serverSide: true,
          processing: true,
          columns: [
             { data: 'title' }
          ],
          ajax: {
             url: uri + id
             , dataSrc: function (json) {
                  var obj = JSON.parse(json);
                  return obj;
              }
          }
        });
```

It looks like the problem was that it was sending back a string instead of something JavaScript understood to be a JSON variable, and as such it wasn't finding the information inside of the JSON.

Comment: I haven't tried this out but why are you reading the Response stream to its end and return this value as the response? If you are working with the response stream, you should be *writing* to it, not reading from it as I expect there is nothing to be read. So I would think you are returning an empty string as response.

Comment: Hey Chris, when debugging responseString says it's easy to the JSON string that comes from the link provided above.  As for why I did it this way, this is how I saw others were doing it and so thats why I did it that way.  If you have an alternative to suggest I'm open to it.

Comment: What about this... the URL at ap.myjson.com returns "Content-Type: application/json" as response HTTP header. Could it be that your MVC code is not setting that header in its response, and jQuery requires it? You can easily check with Fiddler.

Comment: Hey Chris, I've updated the question above, it looks like the problem was that it was being passed back as a string and not as a JSON object, so transforming it when it comes in fixes that.  Thanks for taking the time to help me with my issue!

Comment: Possibly because the content type header was not set to application/json ;-)